# cuda 9 packages no longer required after installation

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-17.04

I installed CUDA 9 from the [local deb](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1704&target_type=deblocal) but afterwards `apt` reports:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
cuda-command-line-tools-9-0 cuda-core-9-0 cuda-cublas-9-0 cuda-cublas-dev-9-0 cuda-cudart-9-0 cuda-cudart-dev-9-0
  cuda-cufft-9-0 cuda-cufft-dev-9-0 cuda-curand-9-0 cuda-curand-dev-9-0 cuda-cusolver-9-0 cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0
  cuda-cusparse-9-0 cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0 cuda-documentation-9-0 cuda-driver-dev-9-0 cuda-libraries-9-0
  cuda-libraries-dev-9-0 cuda-license-9-0 cuda-misc-headers-9-0 cuda-npp-9-0 cuda-npp-dev-9-0 cuda-nvgraph-9-0
  cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0 cuda-nvml-dev-9-0 cuda-nvrtc-9-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0 cuda-samples-9-0 cuda-toolkit-9-0
  cuda-visual-tools-9-0 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libdrm-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libx11-xcb-dev
  libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev
  libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxmu-dev libxmu-headers libxshmfence-dev libxxf86vm-dev linux-headers-4.10.0-38
  linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic mesa-common-dev
  nvidia-modprobe x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

`nvcc --version` reports `V9.0.176` and I have the following in `/usr/local`:

```
$ ls /usr/local/cuda-*
/usr/local/cuda-8.0:
bin  samples

/usr/local/cuda-9.0:
bin  extras   lib64      libnvvp  nsightee_plugins  nvvm    samples  src      tools
doc  include  libnsight  LICENSE  nvml              README  share    targets  version.txt
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The current CUDA installed by local deb is CUDA 9.1   So it would make sense that the CUDA 9.0 packages are no longer required.  Having said that, without knowing the full history of exactly what you did with this machine, it's probably not possible to give a specific answer.

Comment: Hmm. `nvcc --version` reports `V9.0.176`, but maybe I do have a newer version installed. Any other way to check?

Comment: Click on your local deb link that you put in your question.  Then look at the top of the page. Does it say 9.0 or 9.1?  If it says 9.1, and you actually used that to install CUDA, then I would say you did something wrong and your install is broken.  It certainly should have installed CUDA 9.1  Maybe you have CUDA 9.0 and CUDA 9.1 installed, and you forgot to update the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables.

Comment: Like I said, without an exact recording of what you did and the exact steps you followed, it's just guesswork.  If you get your installer from where you linked, and you follow the instructions in the [linux install guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) carefully, you should get/have CUDA 9.1, not 9.0.  What directories of the form `cuda-X.Y` do you have listed in `/usr/local` ?

Comment: I did this a little while back so that's why it's 9.0. However apt reported them "no longer required" immediately after I installed iirc. In `/usr/local` I have `cuda-8.0` and `cuda-9.0`.

Comment: I went ahead and removed everything then installed CUDA 9.1 and everything looks good now. Thanks for your help

Comment: For me this happened because I attempted to install the 32bit nvidia libraries (libnvidia-gl-418:i386) so that I can have a native installation of steam and cuda side-by-side (appears impossible at this moment). https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/6297

Answer (score 1):

I could not determine why the CUDA 9.0 packages were "no longer required", but I went ahead and removed all old packages and then installed CUDA 9.1 from the local deb linked in my question.

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt --purge remove cuda-repo-ubuntu1704-9-0-local

sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1704-9-1-local_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-9-1-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cuda
```

And then I verified `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin` was in my `$PATH`, and I added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin` to my `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Don't forget to update your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables as discussed in the [linux install guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html).

Comment: Right! Did it and added the info to this answer. Thanks again.